# Is there any way to get a Text Linear Gradient with React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, gradient

I've searched for existing component to create a linear gradient on a text but I can't find anything to do it.

I need to have an opacity linear gradient applied on some text, in my case from 1 to 0.5.

I'm wondering how I could reproduce something like that?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: SVG http://lea.verou.me/2012/05/text-masking-the-standards-way/, or of course `<Canvas>` :)

Comment: @AshleyCoolman with React Native? How?

Comment: Oh wow, i missed the "react native" part of the question. But as i understand it you can stringify functions and send then them to a WebView to be executed - giving you anything you want from the HTML API. There are a few experimental packages around that help with that. But the short version of this comment is - I dont know a good way ;)

Comment: Yeah I don't want to use a webview, that's not the good solution...